# remove duplicate json results in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm building an api in Flask that fetches a list of blog posts and is filtered by a tag variable. When multiple tags are sent to the api, it returns any post with either of those tags. My problem is that it's returning some duplicate results when more than one tag is used. So when I use this:

```
@app.route('/api/posts')
def Posts():
  tag_str = request.args.get("tags")
  if tag_str == None:
    return {"Error": "Tags parameter is required"}, 400
  tags = tag_str.split(",")

  data = []

  for tag in tags:
      blog = requests.get(f"https://hatchways.io/api/assessment/blog/posts?tag={tag}").json()
      data += blog["posts"]
```

i get back:

```
> "posts": [
    {
      "author": "Rylee Paul", 
      "authorId": 9, 
      "id": 1, 
      "likes": 960, 
      "popularity": 0.13, 
      "reads": 50361, 
      "tags": [
        "tech", 
        "health"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "author": "Rylee Paul", 
      "authorId": 9, 
      "id": 1, 
      "likes": 960, 
      "popularity": 0.13, 
      "reads": 50361, 
      "tags": [
        "tech", 
        "health"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "author": "Zackery Turner", 
      "authorId": 12, 
      "id": 2, 
      "likes": 469, 
      "popularity": 0.68, 
      "reads": 90406, 
      "tags": [
        "startups", 
        "tech", 
        "history"
      ]
```

The id is a unique value, so how do I do an if statement that basically checks to see if that id already exists in the list and appends it if it isn't?

Comment: `if data["id"] in [p["id"] for p in blog["posts"]]`

Comment: I tried something similar, but get: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below should work

```
posts = [
    {
        "author": "Rylee Paul",
        "authorId": 9,
        "id": 1,
        "likes": 960,
        "popularity": 0.13,
        "reads": 50361,
        "tags": [
            "tech",
            "health"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author": "Rylee Paul",
        "authorId": 9,
        "id": 1,
        "likes": 960,
        "popularity": 0.13,
        "reads": 50361,
        "tags": [
            "tech",
            "health"
        ]
    },
    {
        "author": "Zackery Turner",
        "authorId": 12,
        "id": 2,
        "likes": 469,
        "popularity": 0.68,
        "reads": 90406,
        "tags": [
            "startups",
            "tech",
            "history"]
    }
]

post_ids = set()
filtered_posts = []
for p in posts:
    if p['id'] not in post_ids:
        filtered_posts.append(p)
        post_ids.add(p['id'])
print(filtered_posts)
```